# Where can i get power for my exhaust fan in my bathroom?

Tags: electrical, exhaust-fan

I’m trying to install an exhaust fan in my bathroom just a fan no light. Can i get the power from the light switch or from the GFI outlet ??

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but the devil is in the details.

- Switch

The advantage of pulling power from the light switch is that you will likely want the fan switch in the same location. Depending on the setup, that might be replacing a single switch with a double switch or it might be adding a separate switch that includes a timer and/or humidity sensor.

However, the existing light switch might be a *switch loop*. A switch loop has a hot wire (which you need) and a switched hot wire (to the light) but does not necessarily have a neutral wire (which you need to power the fan). The only way to tell is to open up the switch box and see what wires are in there. If you have black and/or red wires connected to the light switch and a group of 2 or more white wires in a wire nut then you almost certainly have neutral available. On the other hand, if the switch has a black wire and a white wire and there are no other wires in the switch box except ground wires then you don't have neutral and you have to go to the receptacle for power.

- Receptacle

A GFCI receptacle can provide the power you need in two ways: *line* and *load*. The key difference is that with load the fan will be GFCI protected and with line it will not. GFCI protection is generally a good thing, but generally *not* required for fans and lights *except* if they are above a tub or shower.

- New Wiring

Either way, you will need some new wiring. In most parts of the US that means non-metallic (NM) cable, a.k.a., Romex. You will need to run at least one cable, possibly two cables. If you are able to get power from an existing switch and you are OK with putting the new switch next to it then you only need to run a 2-wire (plus ground) cable from the switch box to the fan location. If you are getting power from a receptacle and you want the switch someplace other than at the receptacle, you will need to either run a 2-wire cable from the receptacle to the new switch and a 2-wire cable from the switch to the fan, or run a 3-wire cable from the receptacle to the switch and a 2-wire cable from the receptacle to the fan.

- Ductwork

This is often the hardest part. An exhaust fan does no good if the air doesn't go outside. While most electrical wiring can be done with no work on the walls/ceiling or minimal work (and minimal patching) on the walls and ceciling, the ductwork will generally require either much more work on the ceiling (and possibly in other rooms if the bathroom is not on an outside wall or on the top level for roof access) or access to the attic (if the bathroom is on the top level). The details vary quite a bit.